# JMS with ActiveMQ Artemis configuration problem

Tags: activemq-artemis, jboss-eap-7

Have been trying to deploy Java EE application on JBoss EAP 7.2 which uses one `@ApplicationScoped` producer class, it creates topic and sends message and one `MessageDrivenBean`, which overrides `onMessage` method. Deployment is unsuccessful due to following errors:

```
18:15:14,260 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (management-handler-thread - 6) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("redeploy") failed - address: ([("deployment" => "MQTesting.war")]) - failure description: 
{
    "WFLYCTL0412: Required services that are not installed:" => ["jboss.naming.context.java.module.MQTesting.MQTesting.DefaultJMSConnectionFactory"],
    "WFLYCTL0180: Services with missing/unavailable dependencies" => ["jboss.naming.context.java.module.MQTesting.MQTesting.env.ActiveMQProducer.connectionFactory is missing [jboss.naming.context.java.module.MQTesting.MQTesting.DefaultJMSConnectionFactory]"]
}
18:15:14,260 ERROR [org.jboss.as.server] (management-handler-thread - 6) WFLYSRV0011: Redeploy of deployment "MQTesting.war" was rolled back with the following failure message: 
{
    "WFLYCTL0412: Required services that are not installed:" => ["jboss.naming.context.java.module.MQTesting.MQTesting.DefaultJMSConnectionFactory"],
    "WFLYCTL0180: Services with missing/unavailable dependencies" => ["jboss.naming.context.java.module.MQTesting.MQTesting.env.ActiveMQProducer.connectionFactory is missing [jboss.naming.context.java.module.MQTesting.MQTesting.DefaultJMSConnectionFactory]"]
}
```

I'm using standalone.xml as JBoss configuration file. `DefaultJMSConnectionFactory` is created in `standalone.xml` file.
I'm trying to get connection factory this way:

```java
@Resource
private ConnectionFactory connectionFactory;
```

Also copied Wildfly extension for messaging and messaging subsystem from `standalone-full.xml`.

Message Driven Bean, which implements `MessageListener` is started as it is shown in log file. However, after that this error happens and deployment is unsuccessful.

edit:
It is giving me this error on `standalone-full.xml` and Server boot fails.

```
ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("add") failed - address: ([
    ("subsystem" => "messaging-activemq"),
    ("server" => "default")
]) - failure description: {
    "WFLYCTL0412: Required services that are not installed:" => ["jboss.http-upgrade-registry.default"],
    "WFLYCTL0180: Services with missing/unavailable dependencies" => ["jboss.messaging-activemq.default is missing [jboss.http-upgrade-registry.default]"]
}
```

Comment: Does your application deploy if you use `standalone-full.xml` rather than your modified `standalone.xml`?

Comment: No, it doesn't. But I had problem deplyoing with standalone.xml at first too. Should I switch to standalone-full.xml?

Comment: I would switch to `standalone-full.xml` at least until you get it working since `standalone-full.xml` is guaranteed to have all the necessary JMS resources configured by default. If it doesn't work when using `standalone-full.xml` then you know the problem is with your application rather than the messaging configuration. Once you get everything working with `standalone-full.xml` then you can copy all the necessary config to `standalone.xml` and use that.

Comment: Did you resolve your issue?

Comment: Unfotunately, no :( switched to `standalone-full.xml` and now it says that jboss.messaging-activemq.default is missing. Don't know what to do anymore.

Comment: Are you sure that nothing was changed in your `standalone-full.xml`? Can you post the full `standalone-full.xml` which you're using?

Comment: Finally `standalone.xml` started working. Tried so many things that don't even remember what worked. Thank you! :)